# how to do a where with a condition both in the object and in an associated object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two classes a ProductList and a List. A ProductList associates a product into a list. A list can be of different types (list_type_id). A ProductList has_many products and has_many lists.

I'd like to get back a count of a specific product_id that are part of a specific list_type_id.

I'm thinking something like this:

```
ProductList.where('product_id=123').where('list.list_type_id=7').count
```

but this doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?

thx

Comment: I guess posting more of your code from models (relationships etc.) will help you get a quicker and precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
ProductList.joins(:lists)
  .where("product_lists.product_id = ? AND lists.list_type_id = ?", 123, 7)
```

Im not sure about `product_lists`, maybe it should be like `productlists`